# Wondering where to find docs on serverless dynamoDB Schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am writing the following for a db schema:
resources:

```
Resources:
    DynamoDbTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:

        TableName: EmployeeType
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: timeoffgroupid
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: timeOffGroup
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: timeOffGroupColor
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: timeoffgroupid
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: timeOffGroup
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: timeOffGroupColor
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 5
          WriteCapacityUnits: 5
    DynamoDBIamPolicy:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
      DependsOn: DynamoDbTable
      Properties:
        PolicyName: lambda-dynamodb
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - dynamodb:Query
                - dynamodb:Scan
                - dynamodb:GetItem
                - dynamodb:PutItem
                - dynamodb:UpdateItem
                - dynamodb:DeleteItem
              Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/moviesTwo
        Roles:
          - Ref: IamRoleLambdaExecution
```

But I copied that from a few tutorials and figured out how to post to a db, but I am not sure what all the options are. For example, KeyType: HASH - what are the other options, what do they do? I saw one tutorial tell me this creates a table and sets up the properties with required keys, but I am not sure how to call one primary or how to reference these Attributes and keyTypes. I understand the S is for String, but I am not sure what the other Properties do? I have looked in the [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/) but came up empty.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resources schema used by `serverless.yml` is the CloudFormation schema. For DynamoDB take a look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html).

To understand DynamoDB concepts and terms I'd suggest to start here:

- [Intro](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/quick-intro.html)
- [Core components](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html)
- [Sample](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SampleData.html)

Comment: Much more what I was looking for. Thought it was in serverless, didn't realize it was aws docs. Thanks.